# Div-content visible althought div-height = 0

Tags: html, css, height

I made an ul inside a div. I expected the ul to disappear when I set div {height: 0;} but the list is still visible.

overflow:hidden makes the list invisible, but it seems that it still has impact on the div's height.

diaplay:none works, but the list should have a transition effect. That's why I want set height to 0.

how cam I make the list disappear and come back with transition?

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: gray
}

.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  background-color: #ff7f7f;
}

.toggle ul li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 6vh;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-size: 3vh;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">

  <ul>
    <li>AAA</li>
    <li>BBB</li>
    <li>CCC</li>
    <li>DDD</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>EEE</li>
    <li>FFF</li>
    <li>GGG</li>
    <li>HHH</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

[`isolated problem`](https://codepen.io/Meeka/pen/mGwdVb)

[full problem](https://codepen.io/Meeka/pen/xarbvg)

[image of full problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1uFc.png)
It should look like using display: none, because overflov:hidden still has impact on the layout.

Comment: you must have use `overflow:hidden` for `height:0px` working

Comment: the list is invisible, but still seems to have height, which has visible effect on the layout @BhargavChudasama
You may can have a look on the "full problem" link?

Comment: You have `margin-top: 5vh;` on the `.toggle` class in your full example … the element’s height _is_ 0 as expected, but the margins you specified for the element are of course still respected.

Comment: That's it. Thx so much @misorude!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `margin-top: 5vh;` on the `.toggle` class in your full example.

The element’s height *is* 0 as expected, but the margins you specified for the element are of course still respected.